# Exclude items from a <?php include

Tags: php, html

I am making a site which is required to have an `<aside>` bar and in this will contain an inclued PHP page. It is to appear on every page of the site and the includes will include a side nav for secondary pages like Contact and Privacy.

This will mean of course that everything on the PHP page will always be inclued but, for example, on the privacy page (since you're already looking at it) I do not require this item to be present on the included items. Similarly with the contact page, I would then want the privacy button to appear but the contact button removed.

Is there a way to do this? The reason I have to ask is that I don't know if an additional language needs to be used or if PHP will do the entire thing (when I organise it too).

It's just a very simple

```
<?php include('aside.php');?>
```

aside.php

```
<?php echo '
   Side Nav Content here
'?>
```

Comment: The code inside aside.php needs to conditionally output or not output stuff. There's no way to control that from the including side (except perhaps by setting some variables that cause the conditional code in aside.php to output or not output stuff). Break it down into more modular pieces which you can include selectively, or perhaps functions which you can call selectively and/or pass parameters…

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I did think it would involve either an extra language or some kind of added funtion. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your include function `<?php include('aside.php');?>` inner condition. Like that:

```php
<?php 

$uriFragments = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2); // for Example [  "contact", "foo", "bla" ];
$notShowedOn = ['contact', 'about-us'];

if(! in_array($uriFragments[0], $notShowedOn)) {
   include('aside.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Maik Lowry .. First I am working out the full meaning and that's going well. On the face of it this looks like what I need. Hopefully get a chance to try it this afternoon. Thanks again, will back to vote you up.

Comment: @CuteyfromCuteCode Thank you for Feedback and you welcome! It would be nice if my answer would helpful that you accept it. Thanks :-)

Comment: @CuteyfromCuteCode Small note. I didnt know about your url structure. I suggest that the relavant part in your url is after the domain like yourdomain.com/contact. Then the key [0] would be work. If it is on a othe position you have change the key.  `$uriFragments[0],`

Comment: Thanks again, the file and folder structure is as you thought, all main pages for indexing and the main bulk of the site are inside a folder each at the root url `.co.uk/contact` `.co.uk/privacy` `.co.uk/services` etc. However, those `includes` php pages and things like my main nav and other stuff are all inside an ASSETS folder and then a folder of their own > `.co.uk/assets/css` `.co.uk/assets/php` `.co.uk/assets/img` `.co.uk/assets/js` etc.

Comment: @CuteyfromCuteCode ok. It was a question? ;-)

Comment: No I don't suppose it was :) I have something to go on and I know where to start I will try and get it worked out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243655/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-cutey-from-cute-code).

Comment: @CuteyfromCuteCode  All right! If you have any questions, ping me here in the comments. Happy to help you.

Comment: Now had a chance to try this Maik and it worked perfectly. Really do appreciate the help.

Comment: @CuteyfromCuteCode You welcome! Merci